# Turning my ATX computer to a mini-ITX computer

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, sata, case, thin-mini-itx

Four years ago, I built a computer. Currently, I want to transfer the parts to a mini-ITX case and motherboard. I also need support for a SATA SSD

- Under 200 dollars. I would prefer to spend less though.
- A case that is designed to be portable.
- SATA support
- ATX PSU (RM650x 2018)
- 2 DDR4 ram slots

If something is slightly outside of my budget but really good for my needs, then I am willing to hunt for used parts.

Comment: check out `iwin mini itx`; you can find on amazon also, comes with a power supply, space for 2 ssd's, and is the smallest case I have found

Comment: https://www.in-win.com/en/gaming-chassis/b1-mesh